# Display Native AdMob Ads inside a GridView - Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, admob

I want to display the Native AdView inside the GridView layout. Inside Adapter i've created two different view that extends ViewHolder and return specific view for specific position. Code is as below:

**OnCreateViewHolder()**

```
//Inflate Custom Layout for View
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = null;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;

    if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.video_list_ad_view_layout, parent, false);
        vh = new VideoAdapter.AdViewHolder(itemView);

    } else {

        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.video_card_layout, parent, false);
        vh = new VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    return vh;
}
```

**AdView Holder Class:**

```
//Separate AdViewHolder for displaying the Ads in the list
private static class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    AdView mAdView;

    AdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(String.valueOf(R.string.test_device_id))
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

**VideoViewHOlder()**

```
public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //Code is here for custom videoViewHolder

}
```

This Ads are displayed inside a GridView layout with other Grid Items. I tried to set the size of the AdView but it doesn't help me out.

I need some solution so i can display NativeAds inside GridLayout as GridItem.

Image Can be found at:
[Google Plus POST with Image Here](https://plus.google.com/+PurvikRana/posts/H4MHy775Fyh)